# JSON or Form Data? What's the preferred way to send data back to the server

Tags: ajax, django, angularjs

I'm messing around with Django and AngularJS, attempting to send data back to my server using the $http resource.  It looks like I could do this by either posting the data back as a form by setting the content-type as follows:

```
$http({
    url: url,
    data: form_encoded_data,
    method: 'POST',
    headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
});
```

Or post back JSON in the request body with something like this:

```
$http.post(url, json_data)
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    ...
}
```

In the first method, I can get access to the form data in my Django view via request.POST, and in the second, I can get access to the JSON via request.body.  They both seem to work, but what's considered best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use the $http service that accepts an object literal for configuration:

```
 $http({method:'POST',url:'api/customers/add', data: customer})
      .success(function(data) {
           ...
       });
```

The result is promise object where you can immediately call .success. Its cleaner and easier to read IMO.

Note: customer is typically a data-bound object literal in JSON notation, but it does not have to be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the convention for JSON data is. What I *am* sure of is that there is a convention for getting form data. In the absence of a compelling reason to use JSON, I would tend to think it's better to stick with the request.POST

Answer (score 1):

I would go with using a form, it just makes sense intuitively and it is what I have used every time.